# Отобразить в браузере видео с RTSP камеры

Tags: html5, видео, rtsp

Есть камера, которая не поддерживает http запросы. Обратиться к ней можно только по протоколу RTSP. В плеере VLC  я могу отобразить изображение с камеры. Но, как можно сделать это в веб браузере?

Comment: Никак, только конвертировать rtsp во что-нибудь другое

Comment: А во что, например? Так, чтобы наименее ресурсозатратно?